# Steam Api Issue and PHP error

Tags: php, node.js, steam-web-api

Hi guys I've made a website on steam with steam node bot but sometimes after login into steam I have this appear above over my website.

My developer told me is steam api issue. Is it true?

https://gyazo.com/3b72a35341e28761eaee2c8bcbfee7b0

Comment: Steam Api is down, other betting sites their bots are working, while mine is still in the testing phase, currently I ain't sure what is wrong with my bot which suddenly stop the trading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a similar site, is.steam.rip you can make an api call to the website and allow users to view your website depending on the status of steam.

First open the api which is saved as a json string. Decode it and access the SteamCommunity part of SteamStatus

```
$steam = file_get_contents('http://is.steam.rip/api/v1/?request=SteamStatus') or die("Is.Steam.RIP is currently offline");
$json_a = json_decode($steam);
$steamOnline=  $json_a->{'result'}->{'SteamStatus'}->{'services'}->{'SteamCommunity'};
```

If you put this in a separate file say checkSteam.php and include it in your main page you can do

```
include 'checkSteam.php';
```

and using an if statment:

```
if($steamOnline !== "offline") {
    // Show the users your website
}
else {
    // deny access since steam is down
}
```

I don't know all of the status's this api offers but it often shows as 'delayed' hence I only use the `!== "offline"`

You can find more api's on their main site [here](http://is.steam.rip/)

Answer (score -2):

https://steamstat.us

Try accessing that link in browser (one from file_get_contents) and if it throws 503 then it is Steam Issue

Comment: What do you mean (one from file_get_contents), im on steamstat.us everything looks fine though :O –